# Google App script takes 10 mins for one function but exceeds time limit when replicated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, optimization, google-sheets, google-drive-api

first time poster so I apologise if if im not following the correct etiquette.

So I have code that, in essence, creates 70 forecast docs in specified folders. This works fine.

I have used the same code, repointed the all the folder references, but now times out.

Code is as follows, any suggestions on how I can make this run faster?

```
function createFiles(weeknr, masterIDs, masterfolders, mastercodes, archivefolders) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var date = new Date()
    var textdate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "Europe/London", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm")
    var fileslog = ss.getSheetByName("FileList")
    var year = date.getYear()

    var mainfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1HdG3eJZrIMF-CRpx17Reqdyd7JM5v5ZW")
    var weekfolder = mainfolder.createFolder('Week ' + weeknr + ' ' + year)


    var tempArray = []
    for (var i = 0; i < masterIDs.length; i++) {

        //   for (var i=0;i<masterIDs.length;i++){
        var folderID = masterfolders[i]
        var masterID = masterIDs[i]
        var code = mastercodes[i]
        var archivefolder = archivefolders[i]

        var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(masterID).makeCopy(code + ' DCS WK' + weeknr,
            DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID))
        var newID = newfile.getId()

        tempArray.push([newfile.getName(), newID, newfile.getUrl(),
        newfile.getDateCreated(), "Created", folderID, archivefolder, weeknr])

        SpreadsheetApp.openById(newID).getSheetByName("Main").getRange(3, 3).setValue(weeknr)
        weekfolder.addFile(newfile)

        //NEW UPDATE 14/02 to set the owner to network finance
        newfile.setOwner('network.finance@dpdgroup.co.uk')
        //End of UPDATE


        fileslog.getRange(fileslog.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 8).setValues([tempArray[i]])
    }
    // Logger.log(tempArray )
    // if(tempArray.length>0){
    //     fileslog.getRange(fileslog.getLastRow()+1, 1, tempArray.length, 
    8).setValues(tempArray)
    // }
}


function archiveFiles(weeknr, fileIDs, masterfolders, mastercodes, archivefolders) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var date = new Date()
    var textdate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "Europe/London", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm")
    var fileslog = ss.getSheetByName("FileList")
    //var year = date.getYear()

    //var mainfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1HdG3eJZrIMF-CRpx17Reqdyd7JM5v5ZW")
    //var weekfolder = mainfolder.createFolder('Week '+weeknr+' '+year)

    var tempArray = []

    for (var i = 0; i < fileIDs.length; i++) {
        //   for (var i=0;i<masterIDs.length;i++){
        var folderID = masterfolders[i]
        var fileID = DriveApp.getFileById(fileIDs[i])
        var code = mastercodes[i]
        var archivefolder = archivefolders[i]

        DriveApp.getFolderById(archivefolder).addFile(fileID)
        DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).removeFile(fileID)
        //var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(masterID).makeCopy(code + ' DCS WK'+weeknr, 
        DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID))
        //var newID = newfile.getId()





        tempArray.push([fileID.getName(), fileIDs[i], fileID.getUrl(),
        fileID.getLastUpdated(), "Archived", masterfolders[i], archivefolders[i], weeknr])

        //weekfolder.addFile(newfile)

    }
    Logger.log(tempArray)
    if (tempArray.length > 0) {
        fileslog.getRange(fileslog.getLastRow() + 1, 1, tempArray.length, 8).setValues(tempArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: You might need to process the `mastersIDs` in batches one alternative is to set a timer to stop the function before exceeding the time limit and call a new instance to process the pending items, another is to use "parallel processing".

Comment: im struggling to understand why it works in 10 mins for my other directory but this one times out

Comment: It's very likely that the folders do not have the same number of files.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could log some of the stuff. For example, how many `masterIDs` do you have? How many times are you actually running the loop? Have you checked how many seconds it takes for every individual iteration? Try to provide more information about the execution to see what could be happening.

Comment: Hi, so I have 70 master ID's, its producing 43 files before it times out.

Comment: As said, try to provide information about the execution itself. In particular how much time is taking inside the iteration. There maybe something wrong there that maybe you can change, but with limited information and a lack of reproduction resources is very hard to help you.

Comment: So turns out, the file was simply too large to create 70 files in the allotted time. So I split it down to batches of 30 and its worked perfectly. thanks for your help

Comment: Could you maybe post your solution as an answer so other people may benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

Posted the answer for documentation purpose.

As discussed in the comments the problem was the file size, splitting the copied files in batches did the trick:

> So turns out, the file was simply too large to create 70 files in the allotted time. So I split it down to batches of 30 and its worked perfectly. thanks for your help